# Are portable pen pH-meters accurate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Are pen $\mathrm{pH}$-meters accurate? I know there are large table-top $\mathrm{pH}$-meters, but I keep seeing these small $\mathrm{pH}$-meters online that can read up to 0.1 units. My question is if these $\mathrm{pH}$-meters (look pretty cheap) are accurate or should I get the large table-top $\mathrm{pH}$-meter for my experiment (will need accuracy minimum of 1 decimal place).

(Edit: Is there also a minimum volume of sample I need before I can test it with a $\mathrm{pH}$-meter?)

Comment: I would say that it's too broad. Could you ask about a specific pH meter? Quality could vary across region, price and make..

Comment: I'd say they are as cheap as they look. But then again, a table-top pH-meter can also be wildly off unless you maintain it properly.

Comment: I've decided to get portable pH meter for 'Hanna Instruments' (https://hannainst.in/waterproof-portable-ph-meter-hi991001p.html) . It does seem like a reputable company with a quality product, compared to all the other pH meters I've seen online in the market.

Comment: Several well known instrumentation/measurement companies offer small hand-held pH meters with specified pH resolution of 0.01 - I see no reason to doubt that they fulfill those specifications.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: Is there also a minimum volume of sample I need before I can test it with a pH meter

Comment: Read the manual :-)

Comment: A pH meter is as accurate as it's pH electrode regular calibration by standard pH solutions. If it is not done, do not expect miracles.